# Falha quando acessa uma opção de vetor que não existe

Tags: c++, vector

Fiz a alguns anos atrás um algoritmo de herança e polimorfismo ele esta funcionando corretamente mas se eu digitar 7 que é uma opção inexistente no menu ele retorna falha de segmentação em vez de me retornar nada imprimindo a frase, qual é o problema?

O menu é este abaixo:

> ```
>  O ecossistema tem 0 mamífero(s).
>
>     Quer inserir um novo mamífero no ecossistema?
>     Digite [s]-Sim ou [n]-Não: s
>
>
>     Diga qual animal vai se reproduzir: 
>     0: cachorro
>     1: gato
>     2: homem
>     3: cavalo
>     4: cabra
>     5: leao
>     6: boi
>     --> 0
>
>     O ecossistema tem 1 mamífero(s).
>     Um cachorro, que emite latido.
> ```

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class mamifero 
{
  public: //Class is private by default then it is necessary to use public so that other classes or structs have access to the members
    mamifero(){}
    ~mamifero(){}
    virtual mamifero *reproduz() = 0; // Pure virtual constructor (and abstract, to enforce reimplementation in each derived class).
    virtual std::string nome() = 0;
    virtual std::string som() = 0;
};

//Class is private by default so it is necessary to use public
class cachorro: public mamifero 
{
  public:
    cachorro(){}
    ~cachorro(){}
    cachorro *reproduz(){ return new cachorro; }
    std::string nome(){ return "cachorro"; }
    std::string som() { return "latido"; }
};

class gato: public mamifero 
{
  public:
    gato(){}
    ~gato(){}
    gato *reproduz() { return new gato; }
    std::string nome(){ return "gato"; }
    std::string som() { return "miado"; }
};

class homem: public mamifero 
{
  public:
    homem(){}
    ~homem(){}
    homem *reproduz() { return new homem; }
    std::string nome(){ return "homem"; }
    std::string som() { return "fala"; }
};

class cavalo: public mamifero 
{
  public:
    cavalo(){}
    ~cavalo(){}
    cavalo *reproduz() { return new cavalo; }
    std::string nome(){ return "cavalo"; }
    std::string som() { return "relincho"; }
};

class cabra: public mamifero 
{
  public:
    cabra(){}
    ~cabra(){}
    cabra *reproduz() { return new cabra; }
    std::string nome(){ return "cabra"; }
    std::string som() { return "berro"; }
};

class leao: public mamifero 
{
  public:
    leao(){}
    ~leao(){}
    leao *reproduz() { return new leao; }
    std::string nome(){ return "leao"; }
    std::string som() { return "rugido"; }
};

class boi: public mamifero 
{
  public:
    boi(){}
    ~boi(){}
    boi *reproduz() { return new boi; }
    std::string nome(){ return "boi"; }
    std::string som() { return "sturro"; }
};

std::vector<mamifero *> opcoes
{
  new cachorro,  
  new gato,  
  new homem,
  new cavalo,
  new cabra,
  new leao,
  new boi
};

std::vector<mamifero *> ecossistema;

mamifero *menu(void)
{
  int n=0;
  std::cout << "\n\tDiga qual animal vai se reproduzir: ";
  for(const auto &animal: opcoes)
  std::cout << "\n\t" << n++ << ": " << animal->nome() << "";
  std::cout << "\n\t--> ";
  std::cin >> n;
  std::cin.ignore(1, '\n');
    if (n >= 0 && n < opcoes.size())return opcoes[n]->reproduz();
else
{
std::cout<<"\n\tEcosistema não encontrado.\n\tDeseja continuar? (s)im ou n(ão): ";
std::cin>>op;
if(op == 's' || op == 'S')
return menu();

else
std::cout << "\n\tGoodbye!\n\n";
}
}

mamifero *getDetails(void)
{
  std::string resposta;

  do
  {
   std::cout << "\n\tO ecossistema tem " << ecossistema.size() << " mamífero(s).\n";
   if(ecossistema.size() > 0)
   for(const auto &animal: ecossistema)
   std::cout << "\tUm " << animal->nome() << ", que emite " << animal->som() << ".\n";   
   std::cout << "\n\tQuer inserir um novo mamífero no ecossistema?\n\tDigite [s]-Sim ou [n]-Não: ";
   getline(std::cin, resposta);
   std::cout << std::endl;

   if(resposta == "s" || resposta == "S")
   ecossistema.push_back(menu());
   else
   if(resposta == "n" || resposta == "N")break;
   else
   if(resposta != "s" || resposta != "S")
   std::cout<<"\n\tOpção Inválida\n";  

  }while(resposta != "n" || resposta != "N");

  if(ecossistema.size() > opcoes.size()) std::cout<<"\n\tEcosistema nao encontrado.\n";
  else
  if(ecossistema.size() > 0)
   {
    std::cout << "\n\tAo final, o ecossistema tinha " << ecossistema.size() << " mamífero(s).\n";
    for(const auto &animal: ecossistema)
    std::cout << "\tUm " << animal->nome() << ", que emite " << animal->som() << ".\n";
    std::cout << "\n\tGoodbye!\n\n";
   }
  else
  std::cout << "\n\tAo final, o ecossistema tem " << ecossistema.size() << " mamífero.\n\n";
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  getDetails();
}
```

Comment: Depois de mais de 40 perguntas acho que ainda não entendeu o funcionamento do site. Recomendo dar uma lida no [tour] e na [help}. E ver melhor como colocar *tags*, formatar a pergunta, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviamente que se só tem opções de 0 a 6 declaradas não é possível usar a 7, portanto verifique se `n` está na faixa válida antes de usá-la, algo assim:

```
if (n >= 0 && n < opcoes.size()) return opcoes[n]->reproduz();
return 0;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/AccessElement.cpp).

Suspeito que tenha vários outros erros no código, ainda que funcione.

Comment: mas eu queria fazer dessa forma pois se eu criar uma nova classe inserindo um novo anumal o proprio vetor contabilizaria e controlaria isso.
  if(ecossistema.size() > opcoes.size()) std::cout<<"\n\tEcosistema nao encontrado.\n";
  else

Comment: Pronto. Tem certeza que foi você que fez tudo isso?

Comment: o codigo em si sim mas o uso de std::vector foi um amigo meu na epoca de facul.

Comment: Agora deu certo.. if (n >= 0 && n < opcoes.size())return opcoes[n]->reproduz();
  else
  {
   std::cout<<"\n\tEcosistema não encontrado.\n\tDeseja continuar? (s)im ou n(ão): ";
   std::cin>>op;
   if(op == 's' || op == 'S')
   return menu();
   
   else
   std::cout << "\n\tGoodbye!\n\n";
  }